# My Sql extension error in wamp server

Tags: wampserver

I'm making a simple login and registration web pages using core php. I'm having problem with the mySql extension problem. I don't know why i'm seeing this php error? and how can I solve this? Please help me you experts.and also I don't have idea how to use mysqli. [image: Php mysql extension error]

Comment: I changed my answer, I just realised you were using PH5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error it is a warning!

[the `mysql_` database extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

You can stop this error from being produced by making a change to the `php.ini` file.

```
left click wampmanager-> PHP -> php.ini
```

Find this line, its on line 449 aproximately

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

and change it to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. Your really deserves a plus vote and a thank for your help. Its really helpfull for me.